# Python ElementTree “no element found” exception

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

imports:

```
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
```

*NOTE*: I've looked at other threads on this same exception, and they all mentioned that a potential problem is that the XML file could be malformed; I'm extremely certain mine is well formed, after checking it multiple times, then ran it through an online validator just to double check.

Basically, I'm having trouble calling Python's ElementTree.parse() function on an io.StringIO file object. I know this operation works, because the following code, which is directly above the problem code, works:

```
testXMLInput = io.StringIO("<timedmile><miles>1</miles><minutes>1</minutes><seconds>1</seconds><month>1</month><day>1</day><year>1</year></timedmile>")
myElementTree = ElementTree.parse(testXMLInput)
```

However, the following code doesn't work:

```
xmlOutput = io.StringIO("<logdata><timedmiles></timedmiles></logdata>")
testElementTree = ElementTree.parse(xmlOutput)
```

I tried putting a value in the timedmiles element, but that didn't stop the following exception from being raised:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

What could the problem be? The documentation and other threads don't seem to mention another cause of this exception.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Both your samples work for me. Btw, please don't leave out  the `import` statements when posting code.

Comment: @mzjn Sorry, will edit right now to add imports. Thanks for the pointer. And it's strange that it works on your machine and not on mine. Don't know why it's broken on my machine. Thanks!

Comment: @mzjn Yeah, XMLElements is one of my modules. Will edit imports rn.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use some outdated version of ElementTree?

Run `ElementTree.VERSION` to get the version.

I use version *1.3.0* and didn't get your error (in both cases).
Maybe you should upgrade your software?

I have also another remark: After you *parse* a source file, the result is of *ElementTree* type.
But to perform various operations, you should then run `root = myElementTree.getroot()` (this time the result is of *Element* type) and use
just this *root* element.

E.g. if you run `ElementTree.tostring(...)`, the first parameter should be just
*root*, not *myElementTree*.